# Can't import discord intents

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I can't import discord intents
I have discord.js version 13.6.0

This is the start where I import stuff

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
```

And here is where I get an error

```
const bot = new Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
]});
```

and the error is:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')

Comment: Show us what error

Comment: Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure why this error is happening, but you can pass strings instead of the `Intents` object, e.g.:

```
const bot = new Client({
    intents: [ "GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES" ]
})
```

Comment: Now bot.on("messageCreate", (message)... does not work

Comment: Tried changing it to just message but now "message.content" is object undefined

Comment: Try running `npm uninstall discord.js && npm i discord.js` to reinstall the package and try the Intents object again, I really don't know what's going on

Comment: Text is still object undefined, but, now intents work
So do you know how to fix message.content?

Comment: Log `message` to see if its being correctly read

Answer (score 0):

This is currently working for me:

```js
import { Client, GatewayIntentBits } from 'discord.js';

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    ],
});
```

Possible intents can be found in the docs for [GatewayIntentBits](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/GatewayIntentBits).

Answer (score 0):

i used  IntentsBitField instead of Intents and it works for me, here's an example :

```js
import DiscordJS,{ IntentsBitField } from 'discord.js'

const client = new DiscordJS.Client({
    intents: [
        IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages
    ]
})
```

for more information about Gateway Intents check this link [enter link description here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents)